# Symfony2 - dev environment

Tags: symfony

I was running my application in the dev environment and then I wanted to view it in the prod environment and just replaced `app_dev.php` with `app.php` **only in the URL** and it worked.

But now I can't go back to the dev enviroment :(

My **URLs** are with `app_dev.php`, but the debug toolbar is missing and the errors I get don't have much information and it's relly difficult to debug them, so I think that I'm still in the prod environment.

How can I get back my toolbar and the nice, descriptive erorrs? I really miss them!

Comment: Maybe it is a cache thing. Have you tried clearing the cache?

Comment: Yes, nothing different happened :(

Comment: @Carlos Granados, it's working but the toolbar is wierd - http://s9.postimage.org/7aoiyw7jj/toolbar.jpg

Comment: But maybe there is a problem with the project logic.. When I view it in prod env, it says that the the rediriecting is not correct. Now I opened an old project and there everything is fine.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12086091/security-and-routes-symfony2 - here is the code.

Comment: This is quite weird. Does it happen in all browsers (IE, firefox, chrome...)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15698/discussion-between-carlos-granados-and-faery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that some css interfered with the style of the toolbar. Solved after some investigation.

Comment: I added some styling to all the images which infected the images on the toolbar, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just restore the file according to your version. Pick contents from Symfony2 repository:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/web/app_dev.php

---

**UPDATE**

Have you tried to access the application via `app_dev.php` again? :)

Comment: It came back, but now is enormous and takes the half of the screen :(

Comment: He replaced app_dev.php with app.php in the URL, he did not replace the file!

Comment: I'm a girl :) and yes, I replaced only the URL, I also cleared cache, but now the toolbar takes the half of the screen...

Comment: Yes, I tried many times... Here is how it looks like - http://s9.postimage.org/7aoiyw7jj/toolbar.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Do one more quick thing please:

- Clear your cache first (on the command line: ./app/console cache:clear )
- And try to access your your site mysite.com/app_dev.php

Fore more information [visit](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html)